# Could not mount /dev/sdc1 but I don't have such a drive!

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount, fstab

Before you crucify me for saying something incorrect, I am an absolute beginner. Thanks for your patience. I m on 12.04
Every time I boot there are two things that appear. 
The first one is that /dev/sdc1 couldn't no be mounted and then could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.

This is what the /etc/fstab looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                        /proc        proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid                  0  0  
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=0af05a68-8fea-432e-974d-a4f75c172c12   none         swap  sw                                     0  0    
/dev/sda2                                   /media/sda2  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,users,umask=000,user  0  0  
/dev/sda5                                   /media/sda5  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,users,umask=000,user     0  0  
/dev/sdc1                                   /media/sdc1  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,users,umask=000,user  0  0  
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                      none         swap  sw                                     0  0
```

My swap is in sda7 and my ext4 in sda6. sda2 and sda5 are the windows drives.

What do I have to change/do to avoid this problem that is slowing down my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your full fstab? It does not show the / (root) line which would mean you could not boot at all?

Did you encrypt /home. It then converts swap to /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 but you cannot mount it unencrypted as you have with UUID for sda7.

Better to use UUID for all mounts. If sdc is external that may be an issue or it may need chkdsk from Windows.

Before anything:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
```

then and you can use # at beginning of a line to comment it out if testing:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Better to use this example and modify it to your UUID and mount point.
For ntfs UUID shown is example only see below:

```
UUID=DA9056C19056A3B3 /media/WinD ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:
(which are the nine characters ” * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than 0×20) 
uid=1000 should fix the trash problems as well:

** To find the correct UUID for your partitions:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
```

** And when you are done editing fstab and saving it run the following command to test for errors and mount the partitions without requiring a reboot. You will know before you reboot if something is amiss. Make sure you have partition unmounted if prevously mounted:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Thanks oldfred. I'm not sure I understand everything. For instance,I'm not sure what edit I should do to etc/fstab.And how do I test it? 
I ran sudo blkid

ebovaguira@ebovaguira-K42F:~$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
device     fs_type label    mount point    UUID

/dev/sda1  vfat    RECOVERY (not mounted)  3E5F-3A2B
/dev/sda2  ntfs    OS       /media/sda2    4820DCB020DCA66A
/dev/sda5  ntfs    DATA     /media/sda5    E848EA7B48EA47C0
/dev/sda6  ext4             /              c5d878fa-4eca-447c-9b0b-d028da278f09
/dev/sda7  swap             <swap>         0af05a68-8fea-432e-974d-a4f75c172c12

Comment: I would change mount of sda5 to UUID as per example. It is good you are mounting Windows system as ro or READ Only, but change to this umask=227.   But what is sdc1? External device? Or was it supposed to be sda1, your recovery which I would not mount anyway. Add # at beginning of line to change that to a comment.

Comment: I have no idea what sdc1 is. I'm sure its an error and I think it is confusing it with sda5. Can I simply erase that line with sdc1? 
I will change umask, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have three drives. sda, sdb, sdc. If you have a flash drive in your system, the sdc could be the drive which will slow down your system if it's usb 2.0. You can move your linux OS to one drive and your windows os to another drive. Remember, the swap works best outside of the extended partition.

At the least, you can use prelink (sudo apt-get install prelink) to have your system to link all of the mount points before boot up. It slows down your boot time, but it speeds up everything else.